# Getting zsh:abort npm start error when trying to run scripts

Tags: npm, mocha.js, homebrew, npm-scripts

I keep getting error 'zsh:abort npm start' when I am trying to run scripts. I am getting the error when I am running mocha tests.

I am using Node v10.22 and installed Node.js and npm using Homebrew tool.

I tried uninstalling and re-installing the Node and npm and still no luck. Can you advise as to how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Code snippets:
package.json

```
{
"name": "api-tests",
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "npm run mocha-test target/dist/**/**.js",
},
"dependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.7",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.7",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.1",
    "@types/uuid": "^7.0.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "form-data": "^3.0.0",
    "mocha": "^6.2.0",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "^1.23.1",
    "mocha-multi-reporters": "^1.1.7",
    "mocha-typescript": "^1.1.17",
    "mochawesome": "^4.0.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.12",
    "typescript": "^3.9.2",
    "uuid": "^8.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.6.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.33.0",
    "eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^7.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0"
}
```

}

When I run command `npm start` I get below output

```
Reading Environment
Creating TestRepository
zsh: abort npm start
```

After this the script execution is terminated.

Comment: Can you put the code anywhere so that we can see the process of how to reproduce the issue?